# Concise notation for NumPy array creation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, notation

NumPy arrays are extremely convenient for expressing many common vector and array operations. The standard notation is:

```
import numpy as np

v = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
u = np.array([0.3, 0.4, 0.5])
```

I have many cases where I need a lot of different short `np.array` vectors and the boilerplate `np.array(...)` gets in a way of clarity. What are the practical solutions people use to reduce boilerplate in these cases? Is there any Python magic to help? Ideally, I would like to be able to write something along these lines:

```
v = <1, 2, 3, 4>
u = <0.3, 0.4, 0.5>
```

`<>` is just a random choice for illustration purpose.

Comment: Unlike some other languages, python doesn't allow us to play with the syntax much, or to redefine the use of operators.  Obviously you can define aliases for `np.array`, but it still be a function.  `numpy/lib/index_tricks.py` has some examples of defining classes so we can use index notation instead of functions, e.g. `np.r_[1,2,3,4]`

Answer (score 2):

You can make a class and a corresponding instance with a single letter identifier defining its `__getitem__` method to allow use of brackets in defining the numpy array shorthand:

```
import numpy as np

class Ä:
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        return np.array(index)
Ä = Ä()
```

usage:

```
V = Ä[1,2,3]

print(V,type(V)) # [1 2 3] <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

M = Ä[ [1,2,3],
       [4,5,6] ]

print(M)
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `import` like below:

```
from numpy import array as _

v = _([1, 2, 3, 4])
u = _([0.3, 0.4, 0.5])
```

Shorter:

```
import numpy as np

def _(*args, **kwargs)
    return np.array(args, **kwargs)

v = _(1, 2, 3, 4)
u = _(0.3, 0.4, 0.5)
```

Or you can use a lambda function: `_ = lambda *args, **kwargs: np.array(args, **kwargs)`

*Update: add `kwargs` arguments by @Jasmijn*

Comment: `_` is a somewhat dangerous choice given that it is often used to store unused unpacked values.  You can use any other valid identifier though ( e.g. `Ä(1,2,3)`)

Comment: @AlainT. I know that. However, the OP wants clarity. The `_` is the only character in python that allows this construction.